# How to bind a custom event to elements loaded on the fly from another script?

Tags: jquery, binding, infinite-scroll

I have a infinite scroll script which works for [my tumblr](http://syndex.me).
It's loading images as I scroll down the page.
However I'm looking to have the images [fade in](http://haw-lin.com/) rather than suddenly appear.

I've found this awesome plugin called [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) which does this sort of thing. And it works, but only on the first loaded images. After that, it's not recognising the newly loaded images.

I know that "live" only works on certain jQuery functions. And [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) might be better as you can use custom functions. But then i still apparently have to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the script, and this is what i dont know how to do. This would mean i'd have to hack the tumblr script which does the infinite scroll, [and it's scary in there](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js), javascript rather than jQuery.

Maybe you could recommend a better way of doing this?

Here is the code that works for the first ten images:

```
$('.theImage').waypoint(function() {
   $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
```

I wish i could just do something like this:

$('.theImage').bind("waypoint", function() {
   $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});

Thank you.

PS the content is miiiiildly nsfw. In fact its sfw since one mildly sexy picture is not even viewable and it's all the way at the bottom. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that `live` doesn't work with custom events, but more that Waypoints only fires it's event on elements that have had `.waypoint()` called on it.  So you would need to make this call after the new content has loaded regardless.

Since hacking the infinitescroll script is out of the question, I suggest you try using the [jquery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) plugin instead of Waypoints.  The way inview is structured it creates an event that is triggered by every element so you can use `.live`, `.delegate`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thing is won't i just be stuck in the same situation, having to use live and delegate which means i have to listen for events that don't help (ie click etc)? I was wondering if there is a workaround, maybe using your script and then a ajaxSuccess listner? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910889/how-to-trigger-a-function-when-new-elements-are-dynamically-loaded Thanks again.

Comment: Btw i added the inview script and modified the code found on the demo page http://mmoss.github.com/jquery-inview/ it basically sees the first image and does no further calls.

Comment: First, the inview plugin you linked to is not the one I linked to.  Please use the correct one, I don't think they are the same. Once again, live and delegate are NOT restricted to native events.  You can listen for the 'inview' event.  An example is provided in the README of the repository.